Kadence Blocks and blank Gutenberg (Wordpress)
For some reason Wordpress won't load page editor correctly. It loads it blank only for this one  particular page (other pages load correctly). I was editing it and clicked to toggle tablet view for further styling. Editor crashed and I can't load it since then.
Page works correctly at front, only editor fails to load.
Console gives me this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at post.php?post=7&action=edit:453:1)
I've tried to:

duplicate this page
migrate entire site to different hosting
purge cache
switch themes
use different browsers (incognito and not)
turn various plugins on and off

None of above worked.
Any idea how can I fix it?

I've went to database and checked page's content code. After some trials I found out that the issue was with custom CSS code that I added using Kadence's internal option. Code contained an "aspect-ratio" property.
After it's removal everything works like a charm.
Problem is solved!
